# WKWebview run JavaScript

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an app with `WKWebview` loading the site.
On the site I have the next HTML code:

```
div class="uk-offcanvas-bar z_page_padding_mob_top"
```

I need to find all elements `"uk-offcanvas-bar"` and run `"z_page_padding_mob_top"` function on them.

How can I implement running this script in `WKWebview` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let script = "var x = document.getElementsByClassName('uk-offcanvas-bar'); for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { x[i].classList.add('z_page_padding_mob_top'); }"

    webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in
        if let result = result {
            print(result)
        }
    }
```

This code is worked for me.